# How can i get element by href using javascript and after that, click?

Tags: javascript, href, element

Hi i have this situation:

href="javascript:void(0);">login

I would like click in "login", but i don't how to reach this element using javascript. Is it possible?

Thaks

Comment: Do you want to trigger a click event programmatically? Learn about the DOM and how to navigate it: http://quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html

Comment: Felix, Thank you. I will read the page.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give it an id, like `<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn_login">Login</a>` and then referring it simply by `document.getElementById('#btn_login')`?

Comment: Becouse the page was made this way, i'm a tester and i'm creating some scripts to automate my tests. I will suggest what you said, becouse is easier to find by ID. Thank you so much!!